# java csv file opening and editing

Tags: java, csv

i have some marks for some students in my tutoring class...and also i'm trying to learn how to open and edit csv files as they're not like normal .txt files in Java so i thought this is the perfect opportunity.

i have a Students.csv file in this format:

```
132567  Amelia
123476  Charlie
123516  Emily
143456  George
123466  Harry
123457  Jack
125456  Joshua
132456  Lily
123456  Oliver
123459  Sophie
123486  Thomas
123518  William
```

The numbers are their student numbers followed by the students name.

and in a seperate .csv file i have their marks for modules alongside their student numbers in this format:

```
123456  51.2    57.3    68.2    72.1
123457  60.4    51.3    70       55
123459  45      60.1    62.7    43.2
123466  37.9    44      67.2    48.5
123476  52.7    78.2    73.3    69.8
123486  45.9    61.2    55.4    41.7
123516  61.2    66.4    72.3    57.8
123518  83.2    78.2    66.1    61.7
125456  69.8    60.3    72.1    64
132456  73.1    82.6    71.2    79.5
132567  56.3    48.8    45.7    61.2
143456  41.9    66.2    55.4    63.2
```

For each of the four modules, i want to create a new file that has all the students results in it. The names of these module report files can be anything for example IR101.txt, ..., IR104.txt. as i can change them later anyway.

i want the end result to be something like this:

```
Module: IR102
Mean: 62.88
00 -  39.9: 0
40 -  49.9: 2
50 -  59.9: 2
60 -  69.9: 5
70 - 100.0: 3
123466, Harry: 44.0
132567, Amelia: 48.8
123457, Jack: 51.3
123456, Oliver: 57.3
123459, Sophie: 60.1
125456, Joshua: 60.3
123486, Thomas: 61.2
143456, George: 66.2
123516, Emily: 66.4
123476, Charlie: 78.2
123518, William: 78.2
132456, Lily: 82.6
```

dont worry about doing the calculations for mean as i can implement that myself.

here is what i have so far, and all this does is open and print the students.csv file but i still cant figure out how to access each value and manipulate it as it's very different to python

```
public class excelfile {

    public static final String students_file = "students.csv";
    public static final String marks_file = "marks.csv";

    public static String[] students() {
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File(students_file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] tmp = new String[14];
        int c = 0;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            tmp[c++] = input.nextLine();
        }
        input.close();

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tmp));

        return tmp;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    students();

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Having said that: you first start by *modeling* the domain you are interested in. For example by creating a `Student` class that represents a single student (with a name and id). Then your file reader code creates one Student object per row. you put those objects into a container, maybe a List, or a Map (because you later intend to access Student objects via their id!). Then you create *another* class that represents *grade data*. Read it in, create objects. And then, later on, you add the computation.

Comment: But as said: that is the *actual* core of your assignment. Doing all these things. Don't expect others to do them for you. We gladly help you with individual steps, but we don't draw the map for you. There are no detours. If you want to learn such things, you have to spent (countless) hours thinking them up. Trying, failing, trying something else, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To point you the (basic/raw) way using regex to extract data :

```
String test = "123 John Maths 15.5";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) (\\w+) (\\w+) (\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d+)").matcher(test);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("ID = " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Name = " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Subject = " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("Mark = " + matcher.group(4));
}
```

The only condition for that to work is to have always the same format for CSV file.
The rest is up to you as it is easy to pars all files and just match each line from a file to a line from a second file.
Easiest way (without using classes, etc.) is to use simple Array or Map (Key will be the ID of student for example so yo ucan easily search for him).